# Check if element has href if it does it shouldn't be empty Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, cypress

Tring to do an if statement in cypress that finds all a tag's on the page and if they have a href then it shouldn't be empty.

This is what I've got so far:

```
cy.get("a").each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el)
     .should("have.attr", "href")
     .and("include", "/");
});
```

However this checks everything even if it doesn't have a href.

Comment: How about modifying your initial selector - I haven't worked with Cypress, so I don't know exactly their selectors should/must be formed - to `a[href]:empty` which should select all `<a>` elements with a `href` attribute that match the `:empty` pseudo class (although white-space within the element prevents the `:empty` selector from matching), and then you simply need to work on those. Also, if you can post an [mcve] sample of your code for those answering to work with it may help us to form answers.

Comment: @DavidThomas tried that but doesn't let you use selectors like that

Comment: @DavidThomas removed the :empty selector and it worked thanks

Comment: Haven't tried it, so I won't post as an answer, but using the selector `a[href]` or `a[href*=]` should get you just the `a` elements that have an href attribute.  then leave the rest the same.

Comment: If my answer below is not helpful, let me know what I missed and I will try to understand your needs and I will re-edit it.

Answer (score 5):

An updated version of Justin Smith's answer that removes the unnecessary callback.

Just to illustrate the readability of Cypress chained commands.

**Remove the noise, just use chaining**

```js
cy.get('Selector for the anchor tag')      // sets <a> as the subject
  .should('have.attr', 'href')             // changes subject to href attribute
  .should('not.be.empty')                  // now test the href
  .and('contain', 'foo');                  // also test another criteria here
```

Note, this pattern has nothing to do with Cypress 7, it has been available for many previous versions.

---

**Checking all hrefs**

The question actually asks for a way to check **all tags on the page**.

For example,

```html
<a></a>                      -- should ignore
<a href="/foo"></a>          -- should pass
<a href="/"></a>             -- should pass
<a href=""></a>              -- should fail
```

One way is to be more selective in the `cy.get()` by moving the `.should("have.attr", "href")` predicate inside the element selector.

```js
cy.get("a[href]")                           // get all <a> that have an href
  .each($el => {                            // test individually
    cy.wrap($el.attr('href'), {log:false})  // here we need to cy.wrap
      .should("include", "/")               // because subject needs to change
  })
```

**Cypress log**

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | get | a[href] | 3 | pass |
| 2 | assert | expected / to include / |  | pass |
| 3 | assert | expected /foo to include / |  | pass |
| 4 | assert | expected '' to include / |  | fail |

Comment: Best answer, but please, replace `.and('contain', 'foo');`  with `.and('contain', '/');` to follow the initial question and bellow test results

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated version of T Gurung's answer.

```
cy.get('Selector for the anchor tag')
  .should("have.attr", "href")
  .should("not.be.empty")
  .and("contain", "foo");
```

Comment: `.then()` followed by `.wrap()` is superfluous.

Comment: @MarionMorrison, I don't think it is, in Cypress 7 at least, the argument passed to then is a jQuery element. You have to wrap it in order to execute assertions.

Comment: It is in your code sample. You are not using `href` in any way other than to put it back in the pipeline with `cy.wrap()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can say there should be no A elements with a blank href

```
cy.get('a').get('[href=""]').should('length',0);
```

or

```
cy.get('a').get('[href=""]').should('not.exist');
```

You can also say there should be no A elements that do not have a href tag if need be, I was not sure if this was a requirement

```
cy.get('a:not([href])').should('not.exist');
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this:**

```
cy.get('Selector for the anchor tag')
     .should('have.attr', 'href')
     .then((href) => {
        expect(href).should('not.be.empty')  //To assert, not to be empty
        expect(href).to.contain('foo')   //If you want to assert for something specific to be there
     })
```

Comment: In Cypress 3 `expect(href).should` is not a function

Comment: In newer Cypress versions you can do `cy.wrap(href).should` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have read comment of Zauni and try it out.

Cypress ^10.3.1

```js
cy.get({selector}).wrap('href').should('not.be.empty');
```

Work perfectly.

Comment: Sadly that's not a sensible test - you are checking the string "href" is not empty.